# GMail API manage labels with Service user

Tags: google-oauth, gmail-api, google-authentication

I'm writing a small script to help our supporters in pyhton. I would like to create a couple of labels for new users, but I'm failing at authentication.

Here are some important parts of the code:

```
    delegated_credentials = self.credentials.create_delegated(self.p.mail)
    http = delegated_credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    self.service_gmail = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

    for i in groupstoadd:
        print "| |-> {}".format(i)
        self.service_gmail.users().labels().create(userId=self.p.mail, body={"name": i}).execute()
```

so self.credentials is working in the same way in the code, with an admin account, so I can create this user before. But when I try to call the ...labels().create I get this:

```
Error: (<class 'oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError'>, HttpAccessTokenRefreshError(u'unauthorized_client: Unauthorized client or scope in request.',), <traceback object at 0x7f205667a9e0>)
```

The funny thing if I use my admin email in the delegate and create it works. So the question if I have to somehow enable GMAIL API on the new user ? (Domain wide enabled APIs for sure)

And the self.credentials part:

```
   self.credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(CreateGA.CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, scopes=CreateGA.SCOPES)
```

And scopes are:

```
   SCOPES = [
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.security',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels',
    ]
```

Thanks a lot in advance !
P.

Answer (score 0):

The "admin.*" scopes don't work with the Gmail API, to use the API to update labels you should only need the gmail.labels scope.

To use the Gmail API with domain-wide delegation (support people have access to any user in the domain), you need to follow [these docs on setting up Domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).  Specifically whitelist the developer project in Domain CPanel and then "JWT" auth flow to create an auth token for each user.  Then use that credential to make the request for the Gmail user against the API.

Comment: Admin scope is there to create the new user, and I think the DWD works, as the service user can take over my admin user and create the user. Alto I have to check that CPanler JWT thing. Thanks for the hint, I  came back if I managed to make it work ! :)

Comment: Okay, the problem was different

Comment: (sorry extra enter) if I wait 60 sec before messing with the labels after the user is created, my code works.... wuuu huuu :) Looks like a timing issue, I guess the user as an entity is created as I can assign him into groups already, buuut the inbox creation takes some additional time... Meh, at least it's working now, so thanks for the help !

Comment: Weird, never heard of that race condition/lag between creating user and using with Gmail API.  Good to know.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the timing, looks like GMail inbox needs some time to be created after the user is created. I tried with 60 sec, of course maybe a retry loop does faster. Anyway, I can proceed now :)
Thanks for all the answers.